# Numbers above the average in excel (SUM)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

Can you advise how I can write formula related to average numbers? 
I have numbers and want to sum only what is above average. For me below the average equal to a shortage of inventory that I do not want to use.

[image]

Comment: Really easy: 1) add a new cell that has the [AVERAGE()](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/average.html).  2) Use [SUMIF](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/sumif.html)

Answer (score 2):

So try this:

```
=SUMIF(B3:B10,">"&AVERAGE(B3:B10),B3:B10)
```

[image]

Note it does exactly what you asked for, but if you want ">=" then you need to edit that criterion.

Comment: Was about to post my answer :)

Comment: @ Solar Mike - Please amend the formula as  =SUMIF(B3:B10,">"&AVERAGE(B3:B10),B3:B10)

Comment: @manoj0790 done and changed the image... Excel worked with it fine though for some reason...